# MSI Registry prepend value not updated

Tags: wix, windows-installer

We are using wix 3.9.1208.0 to generate MSI. Below code prepend the value to `Upperfilters` registry key.

`<RegistryKey Id="UpperFilters" Root="HKLM" Key="xxxxxxxxx" Action="create">
          <RegistryValue Name="UpperFilters" Type="multiString" Action="prepend" Value="xxxxx"/>
</RegistryKey>`

After install observed, value not prepend to 'UpperFilters' registry key and not found any errors in MSI log. This issue happened only once.

MSI Log:

> MSI (s) (0C:28) [10:38:08:835]: Executing op: ComponentRegister(ComponentId=xxxx,KeyPath=02:xxxxx,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)
>   MSI (s) (0C:28) [10:38:24:455]: Executing op: RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483646,Key=xxxxx,,BinaryType=0,,)
>   MSI (s) (0C:28) [10:38:24:456]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=UpperFilters,Value=xxxxx[~],)

Is MSI returns any failures when unable to update registry?

Will all registry failures are recorded in MSI log?

What's the issue in my scenario?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to show more from the log. It's hard to tell what's going on from those log fragments. ComponentRegister isn't typically next to RegOpenKey - it's just a register of the keypath in the registry and not related to the actual issue.

There are few things that could be wrong:

Why is the Component id xxxx? Have you hidden the actual guid when you posted the log information or is that what you actually used? It's not a legal id.

It's a 64-bit system and you tried to update the 32-bit registry. Without knowing the system bitness and your MSI's architecture we can't tell if you updated the required key.

Prepending doesn't really do anything if there is nothing in the existing data, so without seeing the data before and the data afterwards it's not clear if it worked correctly (because there was nothing to prepend to) or failed (because it did not actually prepend your data to the existing data).

Comment: Hide the component id before posting. It's a 64-bit machine and prepending 'UpperFilters' registry key under 'HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}' registry hive. 'UpperFilters' registry key have 'PartMgr' value before prepend.

Comment: It's irrelevant what the system is. The issue is what is the architecture of your install and of the component containing the registry. A 32-bit MSI will not update the native 64-bit registry if the key is in WoW6432.